# Edge PWA not applying desktop shortcut name and icon when using Group Policy

Tags: microsoft-edge, progressive-web-apps, group-policy

When we configure a PWA app in Edge for outlook.office.com it works perfectly creating a desktop shortcut with the name "Outlook" and the outlook icon as dictated by the sites PWA.Json config.

If we use the Edge group policy (Configure list of force-installed Web Apps) to achieve the same result we end up with a different icon on the desktop and the shortcut is labeled as "https___outlook.office.com__realm=xxxxx.com". Not very user friendly at all. Feels like an Edge bug however we do get the same issue with Google Chrome.... Noting they are both based off of chromium.

Has anyone else experienced this or have any suggestions on how to resolve?

Comment: This policy Specifies a list of apps and extensions that are installed silently,
without user interaction, and which cannot be uninstalled nor
disabled by the user. I think this has different behavior than adding the site as an app from the Edge browser. This is the reason that it is not showing the proper label and icon.

Comment: This policy installs a list of Progressive Web Apps silently, nothing to do with extensions.

As a test i configured it to install www.youtube.com. It works perfectly so sorry that's not the reason.

I suspect its more an o365 and or SSO issue. I have a support ticket open but they don't seem to be getting anywhere either.

Comment: Not sure whether you understand my comment. I was comparing the 'install this site as an app' feature with the above-mentioned group policy. Let us know if you get any information from the support case. It may help to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

use "fallback_app_name": "your Text" at the end for example

[{"create_desktop_shortcut": true, "default_launch_container": "window", "url": "https://outlook.office.com","fallback_app_name": "Outlook Online"}]

to change to a friendly name.  I too am suffering though from the Shortcut icon not actually displaying..  works fine if installed directly though edge